# Python crash when adding product of item into a list

Tags: python, list

When I execute the code, python will just execute until the following code attached and stop without giving any error message. This code us suppose to display the square of the number input up to six number.

```
l = []
while len(l) < 6:
    num = int(input("Enter integer: "))
    l.append(num)
for i in l:
        l.append(i ** 2)
print(l)
```

When I run the code, this happen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKt1u.png)

I had test the code and realise the problem probably came from line 6.

```
l.append(i ** 2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to append to a list while iterating over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852143/is-it-correct-to-append-to-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) Also: [Python append element with for ... in leads to infinite loop but not with for ... range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69686813/python-append-element-with-for-in-leads-to-infinite-loop-but-not-with-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here `for i in l` is providing an iterator object of list `l`. with this object you are reading values ie `i` . and for each value read we are adding the value in list l. as since for each value we are adding the value in list `l` thus `StopIteration` exception is not hitting. and you are not able to exit the program and it runs infintetly.

to replicate it you can do something like below

```
>>> def give_iter(array):
...     return iter(array)
... 
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> x = give_iter(l)
>>> next(x)
1
>>> next(x)
2
>>> l.append(4)
>>> next(x)
3
>>> l.append(5)
>>> next(x)
4
>>> l.append(6)
>>> next(x)
5
```

so here `next(x)` never hit exception `stopIteration` and will keep continuing

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new list and append to this one so you don't iterate infinitely:

```
l = []
ll = []
while len(l) < 6:
    num = int(input("Enter integer: "))
    l.append(num)
for i in l:
        ll.append(i ** 2)
print(ll)
```